# How to automatically upload a new file to Facebook Marketplace every day at 6pm?

Tags: facebook, automation

So, I'm trying to automate this Facebook shop. However, the items we sell all change at 6P.M. I can webscrape the data and get it to a CSV file with image, price etc. and now all I need to do is grab that information and properly format it and upload it to facebook marketplace every time at 6pm. Any ideas on how to do it?